# Bug in morrowind elderscrolls: Bloodmoon, no Raven rock

Tags: technical-issues, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I came back to play Bloodmoon and do the East empire questline since you get a house at the end.

Upon attempting to start the questline via "https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Bloodmoon:Establish_the_Mine" 
I find that one of the main quest characters is dead. (Falco)

This breaks the game for me since Carnius will not give any quests after this, stating that "Falco is dead..no more east empire company" (my paraphrase).

Even with using console commands to "resurrect" or try and force quest events, (https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Console) the town of Raven rock wont be built. (just a blank field)

I guess I missed some trigger event for the game to script the building of Raven rock. Does anyone have any solution on how I can fix this?

Comment: Reload a save before you found Falco dead, and rush to him to see if he is dead. Do this with multiple saves back. Try to figure out *when* he died. If the save you find him alive isn't too far back, you can continue playing from there. Is it is too far back, well you will need to so more reading on resurrect commands to get it to work right.

Comment: @TheMattbat999   I wish I could, I dont have any saves before then. Thanks though.

Comment: Oof. That sucks. Like I said after that, try practicing with the resurrect command some more.

Comment: I think you'll need to look at *all* (have fun ;) of Carnius's quest stages, and hope that Raven Rock doesn't have its own stages somehow. Whether Falco is dead or not *shouldn't* matter to a quest that's set to a specific stage. Ask, *what are the console commands to build Raven Rock*. That might garner some insight or a place to work backwards from.

Comment: Can you go back to a point before you started the questline (Before speaking to Carnius) and try resurrecting him at that point?